# Difference b/w creating a RIA Services Solution and RIA Services class library

Tags: silverlight, service, ria

1. what's **Difference b/w creating a RIA Services Solution (i.e. Enabling RIA Services checkbox)  and RIA Services class library (i.e. using a project template)**
2. What are the functional differences amongst the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The library option means you can share it between projects more easily. The solution option is just simpler to get working (not much though).

There is no real functional difference between them. They are just different project structures.

Each RIA services library turns into a web WCF web service library, that you can simply link with your web application and a client side library that you link with your Silverlight client app.

These are not simple class libraries: They are "RIA-linked" together in pairs and generated/shared code from the service library propagates to the matching client library.

Nowadays we always create RIA services libraries in our projects.

Comment: "The library option means you can share it between projects more easily." The same can be achieved by creating a simple Class library that can be reused among other projects. Then what's the actual difference.